# How to check if next index exist - LODASH

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I check in loadash if next index after something exist?

I can find index of page which user have for 100%

```
var calcIndex = _.findIndex($state.get(), 'name', 'case.calculation');
var calcState = _.find($state.get(), 'name', 'case.calculation');
```

However I never know which index go after it.

Is there a way how to check it by index number?
something like:

```
var nextState = _.find...
```

Comment: I still don't think I understand what you are asking.  Perhaps if you provided an example array and your desired output it would be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `name` or `case.calculation`?  Or do you want to run `findIndex` twice, the first pass looking for `name` and the second for `case.calculation`?

I think for the OR situation you would do something like this (assuming `$state.get` returns an array):

```
var calcIndex = _.findIndex($state.get(), function(e){
        return e === name || e === case.calculation;
    });
```

Pass in a function as the second argument that checks for the existence of either property.  If it evaluates to true it will return the index of the array.